# Can Xcode's OCUnit tests run on iOS device rather than simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to run OCUnit tests using my iPad but find that Xcode (version 4.3.3) always 
gives the message `Test Succeeded` even if the test actually failed - i.e. the debug console logs the test as failed.  If I run exactly the same tests but using the simulator the tests fail as I would expect.

For example I created a new project with the following test:

```
- (void)testExample
{
    STFail(@"This test should fail");
}
```

When I ran it on iPad Xcode gave the `Test Succeeded` message:

[image: iPad]

When I ran it on the simulator Xcode gave me the `Test Failed` message:

[image]

Is it possible to get a `Test Failed` message running this on an iOS device?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The SenTesting framework is not complete and it does not guarantee to work with devices, But it does work fine with the simulator. In order to run unit test on your device, I recommend you to use this library,

- [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure exactly what your asking, but the simulator works exactly the same. So be sure to keep the device plugged in to the computer when you are doing these tests. Yes you really do need to rephrase your question, i will be back when you do so.

Comment: Hi comradsky.  I've updated my question. I hope it's clearer now.